# Multiple word search on multiple files in mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, redux

I have a model which has the following fields I want to search.

- title: string
- description: string
- tags:string

tags: string

I want to search all my documents for lets say.

```
var term = 'apple orange grape fruit';
```

So I may have the word grape in one of my documents description and say another document has the title orange and another has a tag called apple and fruit. 
I want to be able to return all documents with these search words.

I tried using the $or like below.

```
  Photo.find({$or:[{title:{$regex: term,  $options: 'i'}},{description:{$regex: term,  $options: 'i'}, {tags:{$regex: term,  $options: 'i'}}]})
  .then((result)=>{
    console.log("Server result = ", result);
    res.send(result);
  });
```

The above only works if I pass one word to the search term variable. 
Example:  var term = 'fruit';
How would I get the result I'm after in mongoose ?

Comment: Anyone able to help with this one ?

Comment: Have you looked at using [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) for this? Seems like a good match.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK that did the trick for me.